# Android & Java: String.getBytes() not parsing escaped characters properly

Tags: java, android, string

I have a Java String `"Hi\n"` that I would like to convert to a `byte[]`, but when I have a variable whose content is `"Hi\n"` and I call `variable.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` the `\` and `n` were parsed separately rather than together as a newline character, so I end up with 4 bytes in the array rather than the expected 3 bytes.

How can I perform this conversion correctly?

Edit: Screenshot added. I set a breakpoint where I'm calling `getBytes()` from, and evaluated the expression when `payload` is `"hi\n"`, and the evaluation returned a `byte[]` of 4 bytes. When I do `"hi\n".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` directly however I get 3 bytes, which confuses me.

[image]

Comment: are you sure about that? I get 3 bytes when i test this: https://ideone.com/nkcNps

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem locally. I get the correct 3 bytes when I run this same code.

Comment: Is the "Hi\n" really a string literal, or some string you've input at runtime?

Comment: @f1sh @Andy Thomas @Connor I too couldn't reproduce this on a fresh clean Java environment, but somehow the Android runtime is telling me `"hi\n"` yields 4 bytes when running it through `getBytes()`. I added a screenshot, not sure why people are downvoting a legitimate question.

Comment: @f1sh it's a string I get from the user at runtime.

Comment: @f1sh I figured out what the issue is thanks to your comment. The input was coming from the user (from a text field) so it was bubbled up to my app code with the backslash already escaped as `\\\`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rookie mistake on my part. The problem was because the `"Hi\n"` example was a user-inputted `String` coming from an Android `EditText` instead of a real `String` literal, so the backslash `\` was already escaped as `\\` and so the actual content of that `String` was `["H", "i", "\\", "n"]`. I added some code to do input sanitization:

```java
// Assume payload is content of an EditText which the user has entered "Hi\n" in
payloadInBytes = payload.replace("\\n", "\n").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

After this `payloadInBytes` is 3 bytes long as expected.